# Is it undefined to return reference to a function-scoped variable as a value?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-value

Is the code below legal?

```
int foo()
{
    int local = 5;
    int& local_ref = local;
    return local_ref;
}
```

If yes, then it's most likely will copy value of `local` to the return value *before* destroying `local`, but why? Neither GCC nor MSVC doesn't complain about this, so probably it's legal... isn't it?

Comment: Its correct. The value is copied. On the other hand, returning local reference would invoke undefined behavior. By local reference, i mean `int& foo()`, not the variable `local_ref`.

Comment: Your function returns `int`, not `int&`, and thus you are not returning a reference. So, you would need to rephrase your question like _Is it undefined to return a copy of a function-scope variable_, and then you would immediately see that is is not really a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its valid. The value is copied *before* both `local` and `local_ref` goes out of scope. On the other hand, returning local reference would invoke undefined behavior. By local reference, i mean `int& foo()`, not the variable `local_ref`.

---

Before function is called, the stack frame is created (space on stack for parameters, return value and as part of it, the current program counter is saved). Then during function execution, local variables (`local` and `local_ref`) are constructed on stack. Before program counter leave the scope of function, the return value (`value`) is copied to the functions stack frame and **after this**, program counter returns to the position stored in stack frame (from where `foo` was called).

For more information search for stack frame.